# Microsoft Error Reporting prevents OSX from shutting down

Tags: macos, office-for-mac, microsoft-office-2011

The error reporting tool with Office for Mac 2011 does not quit when the system is trying to shut down. I always have to kill the process from the command line before I can safely shut-down.

This occurs even if I haven't started any applications that come with office.

I have the latest Office updates and OSX Snow Leopard with the latest updates.

Comment: How is the process called? I can't seem to find it on my system. Do you need the tool at all? If not, just try to remove the corresponding app.

Comment: Heh. I love the title.